# How to customize lettuce connection factory settings?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis

It seems that, at the moment, spring data redis has no out-of-the-box sentinel password.

For this reason I'd like to intercept the redis connection factory and set it manually. Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the `setPassword` method of RedisSentinelConfiguration?

- [`RedisSentinelConfiguration.setPassword()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/48e236059558346fcf7fe6e275b061d9da5dc6c6/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisSentinelConfiguration.java#L246)
- and [the unit test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/48e236059558346fcf7fe6e275b061d9da5dc6c6/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisSentinelConfigurationUnitTests.java#L124)

```
RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master("master);

redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes().forEach(...);

sentinelConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(password));

return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig);
```